# Removing URL and adding container around image in the featured image metabox

Tags: filters, post-thumbnails

I want to remove the url and add a container(div) around the image in the featured image metabox.

Wordpress output

```
<p class="hide-if-no-js">
    <a title="Set featured image" href="URL" id="set-post-thumbnail" class="thickbox">IMAGE</a>
</p>
```

at default.

I want the output to be

```
<p class="hide-if-no-js"><div>IMAGE</div></p>
```

Can I do this using the `admin_post_thumbnail_html` hook? How should I do this?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem, why would you want to do this? Is it because you don't want users to be able to edit the featured image, only view it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you want to do this, but you can accomplish it with preg_replace().

Try adding this to your theme's functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_featured_image_link' );
function remove_featured_image_link($content) {

    $content_edit = preg_replace('/<a .*?class="(.*?thickbox.*?)">(.*?)<\/a>/','<div>$2</div>',$content);

    return $content_edit;

}
```